# BCM4360 on Debian , no 5 GHz networks

Tags: debian, wifi, broadcom

I recently bought TP-Link Archer T6E equipped with BCM4360.
This is PCI card with to external antennas and ac capabilities.
I enabled the card by installing `broadcom-sta-*`, version `6.30.223.271-4`, newest.

I see all 2,4 GHz networks, but can't see any 5 GHz signals, despite card support. I searched a lot and cannot find out is that the driver issue/lack of support for 5 GHz antenna?

I also tried `ndiswrapper` and XP64 drivers. The card worked and I was able to see 5 GHz networks, but couldn't authenticate. I was constantly asked for a password; also my system sort of slowed down. I removed `ndiswrapper` and stayed with `broadcom-sta`.

I'm using gnome-shell and Network Manager. Could anyone help with this issue? I ordered a 300 Mbps WiFi and would like to use 5 GHz antennas.

Some info.

`Linux wilk 4.7.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.7.8-1 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

> lcpci -v -nn

`02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0619]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at fe800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Memory at fe600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [68] Vendor Specific Information: Len=44 <?>
    Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number ec-08-00-ff-ff-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [1b0] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [220] #15
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl`

> iwlist wlp2s0 freq

`wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 54 : 5.27 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 58 : 5.29 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 62 : 5.31 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 102 : 5.51 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 106 : 5.53 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)`

Comment: Not sure. Blacklist Module `wl`

Comment: No, `wl` is the driver for the card from `broadcom-sta`.

Comment: I am not aware of any working 802.11ac kernel drivers for linux except *ath10k* (and if there are new ones, I'd like to know). The 5 GHz you are seeing are likely for 802.11a (and not ac), so you won't see 802.11ac access points.

Comment: OK, but I set in my router mixed 802.11a/n/ac and should see the networks :/ And i checked with `iwlist scan` and found (when trying `ndiswrapper`) that the singal is, as You said 802.11a.